# Unexpected token error in nativescript app on android

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm getting the following error when running nativescript app on device or emulator.

```
Unhandled Exception
com.tns.NativeScriptException:
Calling js method onItemClick failed

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265
```

It happens only on android. Seems to be running just fine on ios. Any ideas what this error is pointing to?

Comment: It look suspiciously like a syntax error. Can you post the code of the `onItemClick` event - it might be useful to pinpoint what is causing the exception.

Comment: @AlexanderVakrilov check my answer below :) It was because using ES6 destructuring syntax needed a v8 flag to work without transpilers.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to using ES6 destructuring syntax in file. Android's runtime is v8 as opposed to iOS's js core.

You'll need to enable the experimental flags in your `app/package.json` to make it work this syntax.

```
"android": {
    "v8Flags": "--expose_gc --harmony_destructuring
}
```

You can further get a list of all ESnext features which are likely to cause problems and may need to be enabled via flags. Just run this command:

`node --v8-options | grep 'in progress'`

Alternatively, consider using something like Babel to transpile ESnext code and place it in `app` directory.